# Fast way to check is image exists in assets in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

My application for Windows Phone 8.1.

I need to find a way to check image aviability in assets resources in my application.
At first, I had following solution:

```
    var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    var folder = await package.GetFolderAsync("Assets\\Makes");
    var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    var result = files.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == imageName);

    if (result != null)
    {
        Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Makes/" + imageName);
        Image img = new Image();
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
        img.Source = bi;
        btn.Content = img;
    }
    else
    {
        TextBlock label = new TextBlock();
        label.Text = text;
        btn.Content = label;
    }
```

It works. But, unfortunately, very very slow.

Anyway, next part of code working even in case if asset is not existing:

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Makes/" + imageName);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
```

In case if file not existing, the image is empty, but not `null`.

Is there are any good way, to check, if image created empty from resource?
Or a really fast way to check existing of packaged resource file?

Thank you

Comment: May I ask why do you need this? In most (all?) cases you should know what you've packaged with the app. Having a special logic on whether something's in the package or not seems hacky.

Comment: @yasen if some external to your app data requires you to load given resource then such query is valuable, you might not have it - or maybe it was not yet retrieved. My case is more complicated. One solution is to keep a list of assets in some xml file, but for me thats ugly solution.